# git: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: github

git push

remote: Permission to VaggelisProggraming/test.git denied to Vaggelis.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/VaggelisProggraming/test.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Answer (score 1):

You should prove that you have write access to the repository you are pushing. Assuming you have right to write, you should authenticate yourself. There are several ways to authenticate. Check [Github: Authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication) page.